# Picturebox not showing other image

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, oledb

I'm done fixing my codes on how to insert image into picturebox from datagridview, but the problem is, it only shows the image on the first row, here is my code

```
private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
            {
                byte[] imagebyte = (byte[])dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells["Picture"].Value;

                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                ms.Write(imagebyte, 0, imagebyte.Length);
                Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(ms);
                pictureBox2.Image = bmp;
            }
        }
```

i think the problem is in the `byte[] imagebyte = (byte[])dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells["Picture"].Value;` code, I don't know what code to replace the rows[0] into selected index.
thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after your `if` statement do this:

```
var row = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0];
byte[] imagebyte = (byte[])row.Cells["Picture"].Value;
```